# linux socket recv buffer packet drops even for "pktcount * pktsize" < SO_RCVBUF

Tags: linux, networking

I am sending icmp echo to 250 nodes in C program.
socket is created like this

```
sfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
```

I have getsockopt SO_RCVBUF :262142 .i.e     262KB
as 84 bytes(including IP, 100bytes on wire)  are required for one packet, the rcv buffer should be able to hold
262142/84 = 3120 packets

```
sysctl parameters  (defaults)
net.core.rmem_max     = 131071
net.core.rmem_default = 113664
```

But there were 10+ drops.

I am sending all echo requests, and then use recvfrom() to get packets.
It is obvious that reply packets get accumulated in rcv buffer of socket,
but the rcv buffer is big enough to hold 3120 packets.

Packets show properly in ehtereal on receiving host.

When I set:

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=1048576
and SO_RCVBUF to 2MB, the drops were 0.
```

Why is this so?

There are few queues in action.

1. the network card ring buffer.
2. nic to kernel que
3. per socket rcv buffer

I guess net.core.rmem_max will change only per socket rcv buffer.

Any links in right direction.

```
Platform Linux suse10/x86
```

### NIC : Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG

-- adding more

I disabled the said wireless interface and started using wired interface
Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5705M_2 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 03)
The situation has changed significantly.

```
net.core.netdev_budget = 300
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 1000
net.core.rmem_max = 131071
net.core.wmem_max = 131071

getsockopt SO_RCVBUF :262142
getsockopt SO_SNDBUF :262142
# ethtool -g eth1
Current hardware settings:
RX:             200
TX:             200
#

eth1 txqueuelen:1000
```

now it is like 0 drops per 250 packets and around 170 per 1000
changed rx,tx with ethtool -G from default of 200 but that had no effect.

then I changed  per socket rcv buffer max

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=1024000
```

this allowed 0 drops per 6000
and 500 drops per 7000

further increasing per-socket-rcv-buffer-max

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=2048000
```

0 drops per 7000 packets

wired net gave more consistent and cooperative results.

But question remains open
when 262142 bytes buffer can hold 3000 packets of size 84(with IP header), why drops happened at 1000 packets.
Even the on wire packet is 100 byte max and 262142 can hold 2600 packets.

ethereal is able to get the packets most of times, and ifconfig counters show no drops so it is something after the nic driver has given the packets to the kernel.

ethereal also missed few packets but that is less occuring.

by changing only these of above

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=1024000
```

drops 96/1000
drops 0/6000

### drops 500/7000

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=2048000
```

### drops 0/7000

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=512000
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=3000
```

### drops 0/3000

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=256000
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=3000
```

### drops 1400/3000

```
hold = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&hold, sizeof(hold));

for(;;) 
...
 if(recvfrom(sfd,(char *)packet, packlen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen)) < 0) {
    rcvcount++;
    process_packet(packet,packlen);
 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a long shot, but since you don't show the complete code, it *might* be firewall related.  Some malware variants use ICMP packet storms, so firewall software could be getting in the way if any is running.

Comment: # iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
#

Answer (score 3):

( reposting my answer from nntp:comp.os.linux.networking )

Following code answers my questions.

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.8.7/net/core/sock.c#L689

```
708set_rcvbuf:
709             sk->sk_userlocks |= SOCK_RCVBUF_LOCK;
710             /*
711              * We double it on the way in to account for
712              * "struct sk_buff" etc. overhead.   Applications
713              * assume that the SO_RCVBUF setting they make will
714              * allow that much actual data to be received on that
715              * socket.
716              *
717              * Applications are unaware that "struct sk_buff" and
718              * other overheads allocate from the receive buffer
719              * during socket buffer allocation.
720              *
721              * And after considering the possible alternatives,
722              * returning the value we actually used in getsockopt
723              * is the most desirable behavior.
724              */
725              sk->sk_rcvbuf = max_t(u32, val * 2, SOCK_MIN_RCVBUF);
726              break;
```

As my packets are below 100 bytes data, the sk_buff overhead would be proportionally quite high. Visually looking at sk_buff, for a 32-bit system, the size of sk_buff appears to be around 200 bytes.

For 100 byte on wire packet, that means only one-third of rcvbuf is holding packet data. 2/3 is sk_buff overhead.

So for SO_RCVBUF :262142,

262142/3 = 87380 bytes are available for packet data.

87380/100 = 873 is number of packets that can be held in it.

1000 - 873 = 127 drops out of 1000 are expected.

What I got was 170, which is not far from expectation.

Following Chapters/Books were really helpfull.

[1] Understanding Linux Network Internals By Christian Benvenuti 
Part III: Transmission and Reception

[2] Essential Linux Device Drivers by Sreekrishnan Venkateswaran 
Chapter 15. Network Interface Cards

- Surinder

Comment: How did you calculate that two thirds of your receive buffer is being used for sk_buff overhead?  Given a message size, a receive buffer, and some network settings, can I calculate how many packets can be stored in the buffer?